# How to store large 2D array in a database?

Tags: mysql, arrays, database

I am creating a custom map data from other sources (OpenStreetMap and ArcGis) and because it is a lot of data to process, once I have some, I want to store them in a MySQL DB, so I can just get them without calculating them again.

Basically I have 1 tile, which contains information like x and y cooardinates, tile texture, size, maxHeight etc. but mainly a 2D array of floats containing terrain heights. A basic tile is 128x128, so there is a 128x128 2D array containing terrain heights for each step.

What is the best way to store all of that data in a table, so when I query the tile from DB according to the x and y coordinate, I get all the required data?

Here is the exact structure that I have in java which I want to store in MySQL:

```
public class Tile {
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private float zMin = Float.MAX_VALUE;
    private float zMax = Float.MIN_VALUE;
    private int size;
    private int step;
    private String texture = "";
    private float[][] dataDMR;
}
```

Comment: if you don't want to convert this array into a db-table, ex [tile_id, row_index, col_index, value] you can simply serialize the array into JSON and store it as `varchar` ?. this could be good if you don't inquiry the database based on values within the array, i mean ur sql qry will be `... where x=... and y=...` then the json option might be good

Comment: I thought about it and it might be what I end up doing. The data is sent in json to other colleagues regardless, I just wonder if there is some more elegant solution. I don't see a possibility that I would ever need the dataDMR in any query, so the json option is viable. The DB is really used only for caching purposes. However, isn't varchar limited to some size? The "dataDMR" is quite large.

Comment: it depends on the actual data size, if float numbers with several digits after the `.` then yes probably you will need larger datatype. i am not sure exactly which one will be ur best.

Comment: The floats have max 5 digits after the decimal point.

Comment: a quick calculation, assuming 2 digits before the decimal, ~8 digits for each float to be represented in string, there will be around `16256` comma, and about 256 open or close `[` `]` .. which sums to about `147296` per array, varchar max size as of mysql 5+ is about `65535` character, so i think to be in safe side, use `MEDIUMTEXT`, you can convert few arrays to JSON and log the string `length()` ... and get an average size for that